# How can I converge the touchpad and touchscreen interface?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, touchpad, wacom, xinput

Basically I want to begin migrating my Macbook Pro to Ubuntu Touch, while only making changes in the GUI. I need to expose the apple touchpad to the desktop as a touch surface, rather than mouse.

Comment: You can flag it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit xinput, which interprets the input methods for interaction with applications. Allow it to see both the touchscreen and the mouse via the same abstraction, then configure this abstraction to accept both styles of input.
Then merge the wacom tablet app with the mouse and touchpad app.

Comment: That other question is obsolete. Now kernel drivers can report abs co-ordinates to user space. But updating xorg is not useful, since Ubuntu is moving to Mir.

Comment: What can I do to solve this right now?

Comment: It depends on hardware. You need to look waht kernel driver reports to user space first, then look at user space driver. I am involved a little in touchpad driver development, but never dealt with apple .

Comment: What command to see what the kernel-user space driver reports?

Comment: You can use evemu-record to see it. Also you can look at the driver code.

Comment: evemu-record doesn't show the output of the touchpad

Comment: the output is from a hybrid keyboard-mouse device, and it shows output only for the keyboard